# angular moment picker use with angular 2 and typescript

Tags: angular, typescript, datepicker

I have messed around for good few hours on this and i still cant figure it out.
I want to use http://indrimuska.github.io/angular-moment-picker/ in the project. The issue is project is made in typescript but any info i could find about this libary is in js. Can anyone make a small example on how can i use this datepicker in a project where typescript is being used?

Currently i have installed the module. Added the script tags to index file. Creaed a js file where the angular.module is and then i call it from a typescript file, but nothing happens.

I tryed using the app.module.ts but i didnt figure it out how can i put it there. I think im missing something or this datepicker cannot be used with typescript.

EDIT:
I found the type definition in the src folder https://github.com/indrimuska/angular-moment-picker/tree/master/src how do i use it? it has different name than the package itself and it is in a different folder.

Comment: typescript is just a superset of javascript, means you can use everything of js in ts (for example casting everything to `any`). did you tried the library in a plain blank js project?

Comment: @FrontTheMachine not mine but https://embed.plnkr.co/plunk/wHiQx4 . Im not very experienced with angular nor typescript. Im just working in a project that happens to use both, so im trying to understand fast how these things work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Angular Moment Picker](http://indrimuska.github.io/angular-moment-picker/) only works in AngularJS (v1). The [example from the README.md on GitHub](https://github.com/indrimuska/angular-moment-picker#installation) uses Angular v1.4.4), The library would need to be ported to Angular 2 since everything was [completely rewritten between these versions](https://dzone.com/articles/typed-front-end-with-angular-2).

Here's the [GitHub issue](https://github.com/indrimuska/angular-moment-picker/issues/124) which will apparently be updated if that ever happens (no news since <s>Feb 2017</s> June 2018):

> **indrimuska commented on 18 Feb 2017**
>
> Hi @janfeyen, thank you for you question. I'm going to write a new
>   project using Angular2, and I think this picker will be part of it. I
>   will notify you in this thread (and also in the README file) when it
>   will be available. Thanks :)

Comment: Aah... i see. ty.